# Sandbox for ACE editor

Tags: javascript, eval, sandbox, ace-editor

I've integrated the Ace code editor (http://ace.c9.io/) in my website and want it to be able to run JavaScript code. The problem is that I heard the eval() function is not secure.  I've heard of these things called sandboxes; can someone explain how they work and to integrate them with the Ace code editor?

Note: I want to be able to run code on my website (so something like an online code editor).

Comment: i use http://danml.com/js/workereval.js . it's worked well for me, but if someone sees a vulnerability, please pipe up.

Comment: you can also just press [F12], and paste into the console, but i'm curious, if this is for an editor, what's the security risk? it doesn't sound like you're gathering credit card info. it's 100% safe to use eval for your own or user-submitted content, just not on content made by unknown other users.

Comment: @dandavis the eval2() function doesn't seem to be working. It just displays a popup(alert) that says Object error. I've taken everything in the ace editor and converted it into a string and run it.

Comment: does eval2() work the same way as eval(). If so, what does the callback do?

Comment: It's not sync like eval is. ex: `eval2("5*45", alert)` the callback gets the eval'd value. i tested in chrome and firefox just now and it's working for me, sorry you're having issues. in eval2, your script cannot use any of the document features normal JS typically uses, because it runs in a web worker, and because the built-on objects that can talk to the outside  have been blocked for security. the only other decent option is to build a JS parser and then interpret the expression with it, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: var code = editor.getValue();
eval2(code,alert);

Comment: ^code gets the code in the form of a string. but eval2 gives object ErrorEvent.

Comment: thanks for trying! i made eval2 for simple expressions, not arbitrary code. in consideration of your comments, i altered the error handling: alert() gives as much info as possible, and i added an exec-only option, which you might need. `eval2(code,alert, true);` will now execute whole blocks of code and return true to the callback if there was no error. If you have a big block _and_ want to capture a value, then you'll need to pass eval2 a function that returns what you want, allowing multiple statements that otherwise wouldn't work inside an eval() call.

Comment: Oh alright I see. So if I wanted to capture a value I'd replace alert with the function right?

Comment: exactly. you directly can't feed many lines of code to eval(), because the code goes in parens, so it has to be a valid single expression. a function is an expression and can have a bunch of code, but you need to specify what to return because there's no intrinsic evaluated "tail value" like there is with eval()...

Comment: Please, did you find a solution for this problem ? I am trying to implement the same in my website.